# Change image based on attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, configurable-product

What would be the best approach to making the main product image change base on the attribute choosen.

For example if the customer chooses colour blue for a t-shirt the main image would be swap to the image which I have marked as the blue t-shirt

Comment: have your configurable product carrying all of it's child product images (color based), then you could have an bit of JS called when changing the color select, which would change the image based on its name.

Answer (score 3):

You can give [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher) a try.
Among other things, it allows you to change the image for configurable products depending on the selected attributes.
You can configure which attributes change the image and which do not.

Read [the documentation](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/README.md) to get a better view.